# ServiceStack: ServiceStack.Common included but namespace not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, ormlite-servicestack

I'm currently playing around with ORMLite for SQLite, following this tutorial:

http://www.curlette.com/?p=1068

This example makes use of the following line:

```
public static string SqliteFileDb = "~/App_Data/db.sqlite".MapHostAbsolutePath();
```

where the `MapHostAbsolutePath()` function is an extension function in the `ServiceStack.Common.Utils` namespace.

In Visual Studio 2013 (Windows 7/.NET 4.5), I downloaded the required packages via NuGet, and I do have the ServiceStack.Common assembly referenced, but IntelliSense does not offer me the ServiceStack.Common namespace.

Do I have to retrieve a separate ServiceStack.Common.Utils assembly or anything? (Didn't find one) Or is that code outdated?

Here is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text.Signed" version="4.0.34" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.94.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually just stumbled upon this file:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/PathUtils.cs

Apparently, the functionality got moved into the ServiceStack namespace directly.

The line

```
using ServiceStack;
```

fixed it.